# Trying to rotate table head to the left html

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have this div:

```
<div class="menu-wrapper">
    <h3 class="pane-title">
        <a href="">Service List</a>    
    </h3>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

After applying some CSS the div will look like in this picture:
[image: mydiv]

What are the best transformations I should do in my CSS to move my header to the left like in this picture:

[image]

It would be really useful if I found a method that avoids using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to use `writing-mode: vertical-rl;` for the heading

```css
div {
   display: flex; 
   border: 1px #ccc solid;
   color: #333;
   font: 1rem Arial;
}

div h3 {
   writing-mode: vertical-rl;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0;
   margin-block-start: 1rem;
   margin-block-end: 1rem;
}

a {
   color: currentColor;
}

h3 a  {
   text-decoration: none;
}


.menu {
   flex: 1;
   padding: 2rem;
   line-height: 1.5;
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   border-left: 1px #ccc solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h3 class="pane-title">
        <a href="">Service List</a>    
    </h3>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: IMO this is much more suitable than using `transform`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) style.

```
.pane-title {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

In addition to the adding `transform` style, update the classname of the parent div container to `menu-wrapper` which is differ from the `ul` classname, and set `display: flex;`

```css
.menu-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.pane-title {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <h3 class="pane-title">
    <a href="">Service List</a>
  </h3>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried using the transform style and using the transform-origin property and combining them with the float property, but I can't really make the elements align with each other. I am asking for that in particular.

Comment: The updated answer is really useful, but I feel like the method provided by Fabrizio Calderan is more suitable in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<div class="menu-container">
   <h3 class="pane-title">
       <a href="">Service List</a>    
   </h3>
   <ul class="menu">
       <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
       <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
       <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
       <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>



.menu-container{
  display:flex;
}
```

You'll have to change the outer div class so that it's different from the inner menu class.

Comment: Really good observation. While making a code sample for the question I forgot to add a different class to the div.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have approached this is by using css grid and separating them into two more easily workable grid items. Then use the transform: rotate() feature in css to rotate the text 90 degrees.

I have only made the grid and rotated it here, no other css styling.

```css
.grid-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 6fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  height:70vh;
}

.grid-item1{
  grid-column:1;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.grid-item2{
  grid-column:2;
  border-top:1px solid grey;
  border-bottom:1px solid grey;
  border-right:1px solid grey;
}

.pane-title{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.title-text{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item1">
      <h3 class="pane-title">
          <a href="" class="title-text">Service List</a>    
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item2">
      <ul class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```